# Usage of tomcat directory by storm LocalCluster

Tags: tomcat, apache-storm

I've been experimenting with Apache Storm, formerly Twitter Storm, and have noticed when you set up a local cluster and deploy the application to a tomcat server there is excessive usage of the tomcat temp directory. I have set up a project that displays this here: https://github.com/dsullivan7/storm-test. It is a maven project so running mvn clean install and deploying the .war in the webapps directory should replicate the issue. It creates 4 files with randomly generated file names. I've noticed the biggest file is the log.1 file in the version-2 directory. Though this is a simple example, the project I ran into this problem originally bloated the temp directory to 5 GB. Is there a way around this issue besides periodically clearing out the temp directory?

Answer (score 1):

`version-2/log.1` file actually created by `zookeeper`. It uses this dir for storing all the snapshots & logs of the running application. This Zookeeper instance is typically created by storm because it uses zookeeper to manage co-ordination between different nodes in the cluster (*coordination between Nimbus and the Supervisors daemons*).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know if there is a way to route those logs to a different directory via the local storm configuration?